# How to call method inside module (same method name in 2 different module) using class object - ruby

Tags: ruby

Consider i have 2 modules, both contains the function 'foo'. If i need to call the Module1's foo using object of the class which includes it, how i need to call?

Code sample:

```
    module Module1
      def foo
        puts 'first one'
      end
    end

    module Module2
      def foo
        puts 'second one'
      end
    end



  class ClassName
      include Module1
      include Module2

      def initialize
        Module1.instance_method(:foo).bind( self ).call
        Module2.instance_method(:foo).bind( self ).call
      end
    end

    cls = ClassName.new
```

How to call the methods foo using the object 'cls' (If i need to call Module1's foo)?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question is unclear. You seem to have solved your problem: The two lines in your `initialize` method call each of the methods in turn. Are you asking how to call them later on, or from outside the class, or..?

Comment: @JordanRunning. Yes Jordan. I can call those methods inside the class. But, i want to call it using the class object outside of the class.

Comment: @Stefan I can call the methods correctly using the instance_methods which i used under initialize. But, i'm not sure how to call those methods using class object, outside of the class.

Comment: I am still on board with @Stefan even after your comment. What is the purpose of this? Why do you want such functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to keep the usual instance method semantics, the simplest solution is probably to just alias the method before you `include` the second module:

```
class ClassName
  include Module1
  alias :module_1_foo :foo
  include Module2
end

cls = ClassName.new
cls.module_1_foo
# => first one
cls.foo
# => second one
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/JQ73

Alternatively, you could pass the UnboundMethod object returned by `Module1.instance_method(:foo)` to [`define_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-define_method):

```
class ClassName
  include Module1
  include Module2
  define_method(:module_1_foo, Module1.instance_method(:foo))
end
```

The caveat with both of these is that if there are other instance methods in Module1 that call `foo`, they will wind up calling `Module2#foo`. They have no way of knowing that `Method1#foo` has been "renamed." This is, at best, a stopgap, and if your code has any complexity at all you should just redesign the whole thing so you don't have name collisions.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Jordan. Is there any way to set the alias explicitly with module name. Like, i have n number of modules and i included all initially. In the alias, if i want to use as 'alias :mod1_foo Module1.foo' something like this (this won't work i know). But, anyway to achieve like this?

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but as indicated in the comments above, it really seems like you have an XY problem. If you're trying to `include` "n number of modules" that all have the same method names, you have a larger design problem that you should turn your attention to instead.

Comment: I have 'n' number of modules, but only 2 have the same method. Others i just need to include inside the class. We have plans to deprecate the method. But, that is not possible immediately. That's why we are planning to call both the methods what we want.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to do the 'alias :mod1_foo Module1.foo' correctly? Is there any way?

Comment: Now that I think of it, you could use `define_method` in a way similar to what you're looking for. I've edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make the modules both mixins (used via `include` or `extend`) and able to be called directly:

```
module Module1
  def foo
    puts 'first one'
  end

  extend self
end
```

Then you can call `Module1.foo` whenever you want. Keep in mind when called this way it is in the context of the module, not any class that might have imported it.

That `bind(self)` trick is some serious hackery that should be avoided. In virtually every case you can re-architect your code to be more naturally expressed in more ordinary Ruby code.

Comment: Or via [`module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Module.html#method-i-module_function).

Comment: @Stefan That's a good solution for a more targeted approach if that's important.

Answer (score 0):

Not so dry but this also works.

```
class ClassName
  include Module1
  include Module2

  def initialize
    Module1.instance_method(:foo).bind( self ).call
    Module2.instance_method(:foo).bind( self ).call
  end

  def call_foo_from_M1
    Module1.instance_method(:foo).bind( self ).call
  end

  def call_foo_from_M2
    Module2.instance_method(:foo).bind( self ).call
  end

end

cls = ClassName.new
cls.call_foo_from_M1  # first one
cls.call_foo_from_M2  # second one
```